# What happened to Mule studio and Maven plugin?

Tags: java, maven, mule, mule-studio

I installed Maven plugin for Mule Studio following by this instruction 
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Converting+Studio+into+Maven

Using Mule Studio, I'm still able to use dependency in pom file, so I create a web service which uses that lib. 
However when I run mule application to deploy web service and call it again, I get an error because of "not founding class in library". One again, I copy *jar into lib folder and add to build-path, then no error at all.

So what is the problem here? How can I use both maven-dependencies and Mule runtime.

Answer (score 1):

The current version of Mule Studio includes built-in support for reading the pom.xml and setting up your project.  Right click the project in Package Explorer, choose Maven Support in Studio, and choose Enable Support.

Comment: Well, Ryan. Here is what I did. Firstly, I created Mule Application, then I converted it into Maven Project, I could still run my app as Mule Application and Eclipse was still able to recognize Maven's dependencies, no error when to build path or complier at all, however, no Enable Maven Support option any more.

Comment: Actually Mule Studio has long ago been renamed to Anypoint Studio.